# Regarding wcf service hosting

Tags: wcf

i am new in wcf and started learning. i got one confusion like that i create a small wcf service and just do not host it in IIS,console apps or win service but from another apps i can add the service reference of svc file and found it is working. if wcf can work without hosting in any place like "IIS,console apps or win service " then why people would alway host wcf service in IIS,console apps or win service. can anyone tell me the reason.

Comment: what do you mean with "from another apps"? Isn't that the same as from a console application?

Comment: i develop two apps one wcf service and another console apps. from my console apps i just add web service ref giving the service url like "http://localhost:21541/Service1.svc" and i saw i could create & call service instance. so when without hosting wcf service in any place when we can call then why people host wcf service. thanks

Comment: Hosting web service in IIS is easy and very convenient. I like how I can quickly publish applications to these servers directly from VS. I also like that I don't need to care about permissions, because IIS takes care of that. I don't need to specify any endpoints in the configuration since the endpoint is always the web app in IIS that the service is hosted in. It's also usually quickly to set up. I see no advantage to doing it your way for client-server based applications. You will have to make sure your app is always running and restart it if it crashes, IIS does that for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

people use IIS and windows services in general because they are simpler to setup and run more consistently. they can also be hosted more easily on servers where the services can be configured to start automatically, and as usually wcf is used as a server communication method it is usually this that you want to do.

hosting in console applications is generally easier to setup for simple examples for testing purposes, when you want to test your services locally.

Whilst hosting in applications as possible it's a less common scenario to use wcf to communicate between 2 applications on the same machine.

EDIT:

Your original question asked why people always talk about IIS, services etc.  The point I was making was that usually wcf is used for web services,  and is usually run on a server other than the local machine.  Even though it can be used for inter process communication on the same machine this is not the most common use case.  This is why you see a lot of examples using IIS and not too many hosting it in a Windows forms app.

Comment: one thing is not clear to me that u said: "wcf service can also be hosted more easily on servers where the services can be configured to start automatically". u r talking about what server. and how service can be configure to start automatically. can u please explain in more detail what u said about server & configuration.